# ASP.Net pages relative paths?

Tags: asp.net

I have a website which i run localy and the path on the browser is

```
"http://localhost:3184/basel/index.aspx"
```

I have a menu which contains various hyperlinks and one of them is:

```
<a href="en/open-account/index.aspx"></a>
//This will evaluate to http://localhost:3184/basel/en/open-account/index.aspx.
```

The hyperlink will redirect me the page above, After that when i try to click the same link again on the menu, the path of the page is the following:

```
"http://localhost:3184/basel/en/open-account/en/open-account/index.aspx"
```

Why is it that the path have duplicated, i have been struggling for a while but can't seem to figure this out, Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="~/en/open-account/index.aspx" runat="server"></a>
```

Using the tilde creates an application-relative path.

Comment: I have tried what you said before and it gives me the following path:                                                        "http://localhost:3184/basel/~/en/open-account/index.aspx". As you can see the "~" sign is impeded on the path and not evaluated, don;t know why ?

Comment: Did you add the runat="server" attribute on the `<a href="...` tag?

Comment: Yes it will. App-relative paths are executed on the server, and translated to site-relative paths.

Comment: So that was is the difference between an asp.net hyperlink and an html A tag, Thank you very much it worked.

Comment: HyperLink is a WebControl, html A is an HtmlControl. WebControls give you a lot more properties that work with webforms skinning api. When it comes to app-relative paths, they can both do the same thing. However the A has to have runat="server" just like the asp:HyperLink.

Answer (score 0):

What is in your code behind?  If the A tag is being set dynamically (maybe something like this `myHyperlink.NavigateURL += "en/open-account/index.aspx";`) then each time the page is loaded the URL will have a new value appended to the end.

Maybe check the code behind to see if this URL is being manipulated there?  If you've already done so, my apologies :)

Comment: There is no code maniuplate in code behind what so ever, and the A tag is on the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Page.ResolveUrl() method. If the relativeUrl have an absolute URL, the URL is returned unchanged. If the relativeUrl have contains a relative URL, that URL is changed to a relative URL that is correct for the current request path, so that the browser can resolve the URL